# WinJS web worker call vs call to WinRT C# component returning a promise

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-runtime, winjs, web-worker

I'm working on a WinJS game in which part of the logic is implemented in a C# WinRT component because it proved to be both more efficient and easier to conceptualize and debug. That component is called on a relatively infrequent basis and returns a promise whose return value I plug back into the WinJS game object.

Now I have a second scenario where I want to speed up an SVG animation by delegating the necessary maths work which occurs during the animation phase to a separate thread and return an object which represents the pure UI action to take, e.g., a list of game objects which should move / grow etc, and have the main thread action that quickly against the DOM (I'm using Knockout). Unlike the first scenario, this background thread interaction would happen for each animation increment, so, quite a lot.

I was going to implement this with a web worker, which I have partly got working, but I want to make sure I understand the pros and cons and recommended use cases of these 2 approaches. It seems that calling a WinRT component and calling a web worker both involve some kind of serialization or translation of the object being passed. For my existing WinRT call I have a WinRT factory class as a property on my js object and I use that to build a mirror simplified WinRT representation of the game to pass to the WinRT component. With a web worker I would have to pass a JSON copy of the relevant aspects of the game and then translate the result back again. Would I be better off using a call to C# again, or is that really only recommended for infrequent calls? What's the relative overhead of each? Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Calls to WinRT objects are EXPENSIVE (that is, slow). Be sure to measure that overhead. I suspect every animation frame will be too fast to keep up. But measure, don't guess.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what Tavares mentions there is no real hard fast rule. Communication between WebWorkers is faster than a call to WinRT BUT WebWorkers are not something you want to create and destroy repeatedly. 
In this case I personally would use a Webworker that I create once during startup and then called the method in it every time I need something calculated.